# How to only update part of db record parameters with django rest framework when do http put?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I encountered one issue when using `django rest framework` and want to get help from you.

For following code, it is ok to use `http GET/POST`, but if I use following command to update `field para1`:

`curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/my_key_1/' --data '{"para1": "hi"}'`

it tells me:

> {
>
> "para2": ["This field is required."],
>
> "para3": ["This field is required."],
>
> }

I know, I can add `para2` & `para3` when call `PUT` method, but this is not what I need. **I want to know if I can just update `para1` without add `para2 and para3` as I do not want to change them?** Meanwhile, still can get all fileds if I do `GET`, and still check all fields if I do `POST`, I mean not discard para2 & para3 from serializer. Any solution?

BTW, I use `viewsets.ModelViewSet`.

#### Next is the main code:

**urls.py**

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'info', views.InfoView)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = (
            'id',
            'key',
            'para1',
            'para2',
            'para3'
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class Info(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    para1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    para2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    para3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

```
class InfoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'key'
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `PATCH` method for partial update:

```
curl -X PATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/my_key_1/' --data '{"para1": "hi"}'
```

Comment: It works, thanks. BTW, does `PATCH` support everywhere? I mean any limit, e.g. every server will support it?

Comment: @atline Not sure, I never heard about any limitations.

Comment: Just through google, some old things not support that, `Apache HttpComponents HttpClient version 4.2 ` early version, `JDK7 HttpURLConnection`, `TOMCAT 7`, because it is HTTP1.1 feature. Anyway, it works for me, these products out of date now, ignore them.